# entry returned on first query, empty on second

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application which allows lawyers and law students to answer legal questions. Their answers can be voted up. Beside each answer on the views/question/show.html.erb, the application  indicates whether an answer has been voted up and by who (a lawyer, or a law student).  However, it's behaving very oddly. Currently, on a test question, if a lawyer votes up an answer, the application is not showing the upvote, but if a student votes up an answer, then both the student's and the lawyer's vote will be displayed, but both are displayed as student votes.

This is the code in the show action of the Questions controller that retrieves all the answers for a question, and then queries for the type of votes each answer has.

```
  def show

  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @answers = @question.answers

   @answers.each do |a|


       @lawyervotes = AnswerVote.where({:answer_id => a.id, :lawyervote => true}).reload
       puts @lawyervotes.inspect
       puts "lawyervotes"
       @studentvotes = AnswerVote.where({:answer_id => a.id, :studentvote => true}).reload
       @uservotes = AnswerVote.where({:answer_id => a.id, :lawyervote => nil, :studentvote => nil}).reload

    end 
  end
```

If I look in the console for the puts statements, it shows that @lawyervotes contains one result, but then it's suddenly an empty array. Currently, there are two answers for this question, which is why the puts statement is run twice, but I don't know why it's empty on the second time through

```
[#<AnswerVote id: 34, value: 3, answer_id: 54, user_id: 37, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:29:34", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:29:34", lawyervote: true, studentvote: nil>]
lawyervotes
[]
lawyervotes
```

Note, the reason why I put `reload` on the end of each query was to avoid an ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error I was getting, which according to another SO answer I found can happen when you query with 'where.' I found another SO answer that said putting 'reload' on the end of a `where` query can help avoid that error.

Can you explain why this odd behavior might be happening with my lawyervotes and student votes and possibly tell me how to rewrite the show action to avoid it.  Thank you in advance.

Update

This is the console record showing that question 62 has two answers, each with one answer_vote. One of the answer votes was by a lawyer (lawyer = true) while one was by a student (student = true), however, they're both showing up as student votes in my application, even after trying dmitry's solution.

```
>> q = Question.find_by_id(62)
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = 62 LIMIT 1
=> #<Question id: 62, details: "I have a terminal illness but don't have time to go...", question: "What happens if I die without a will?", user_id: 35, accepted_answer_id: nil, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:19:48", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:19:48", city: "Toronto", province: nil, province_id: 6>
>> q.answers
  Answer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = 62
=> [#<Answer id: 54, content: "There is legislation that determines the rules of i...", accepted: nil, user_id: 50, question_id: 62, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:20:41", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:20:41">, #<Answer id: 55, content: "Ontario has statutory provisions that detail who in...", accepted: nil, user_id: 37, question_id: 62, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:22:53", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:22:53">]
>> a54 = Answer.find_by_id(54)
  Answer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."id" = 54 LIMIT 1
=> #<Answer id: 54, content: "There is legislation that determines the rules of i...", accepted: nil, user_id: 50, question_id: 62, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:20:41", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:20:41">
>> a54.answer_votes
  AnswerVote Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "answer_votes".* FROM "answer_votes" WHERE "answer_votes"."answer_id" = 54
=> [#<AnswerVote id: 34, value: 3, answer_id: 54, user_id: 37, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:29:34", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:29:34", lawyervote: true, studentvote: nil>]
>> a55 = Answer.find_by_id(55)
  Answer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."id" = 55 LIMIT 1
=> #<Answer id: 55, content: "Ontario has statutory provisions that detail who in...", accepted: nil, user_id: 37, question_id: 62, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:22:53", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:22:53">
>> a55.answer_votes
  AnswerVote Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "answer_votes".* FROM "answer_votes" WHERE "answer_votes"."answer_id" = 55
=> [#<AnswerVote id: 35, value: 3, answer_id: 55, user_id: 50, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:37:32", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:37:32", lawyervote: nil, studentvote: true>]
```

Update

I put this code in the loop

```
   puts AnswerVote.where({:answer_id => a.id}).reload.inspect
   puts "inspectinganswervote"
```

and got this result

```
[#<AnswerVote id: 34, value: 3, answer_id: 54, user_id: 37, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:29:34", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:29:34", lawyervote: true, studentvote: nil>]
inspectinganswervote
[#<AnswerVote id: 35, value: 3, answer_id: 55, user_id: 50, created_at: "2013-05-08 18:37:32", updated_at: "2013-05-08 18:37:32", lawyervote: nil, studentvote: true>]
inspectinganswervote
```

Update

Answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :accepted, :content, :question_id, :user_id

  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answer_votes
  has_and_belongs_to_many :watchers, :join_table => "answer_watchers", :class_name => "User"
  has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
  has_reputation :lawyervotes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
  has_reputation :studentvotes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
  has_reputation :best, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
  # 


  def add_to_watchers(user)
    self.watchers << user unless self.watchers.include?(user)
  end 

    after_create :creator_watches_me
  private 

  def creator_watches_me
    self.watchers << user unless self.watchers.include?(user)
  end 


end
```

AnswerVote.rb

```
class AnswerVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :answer_id, :user_id, :value, :answer, :lawyervote, :studentvote

  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :answer_id, scope: :user_id
  validates_inclusion_of :value, in: [1,-1,10,-10, 3]
  validate :ensure_not_author

 scope :lawyers, where(lawyervote: true)
scope :students, where(studentvote: true)


  def ensure_not_author
    errors.add :user_id, "is the author of the answer" if answer.user_id == user_id
  end

end
```

Comment: why are you doing `reload` after ever AnswerVote query?

Comment: @PuneetGoyal it's explained in the second to last paragraph of the OP. Please let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: it appears `Answer` `has_many` `AnswerVote`. Can you not do `@lawyervotes = a.answer_votes.where(:lawyervote => true)`?

Comment: First of all, I'd write something like : `@lawyervotes = a.answer_votes.lawyers` and `@studentvotes = a.answer_votes.students`, where lawyers and students are scopes defined in AnswerVote model.

Comment: @PuneetGoyal I just tried it, but same problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: well, then the second answer mustn't have any `laywervotes` as per the query condition. can you add: `puts AnswerVote.where({:answer_id => a.id}).reload.inspect` to the loop?

Comment: @DmitriyUgnichenko I tried to write the scope methods but they're breaking my application. Can you please have a look at the update in the OP if you have time.

Comment: Could you also please show your models (for Answer and AnswerVote) and the errors you get.

Comment: @PuneetGoyal I put that code in the loop (see OP) as well as ran the queries in the console showing that the two answers for the Question should each have one vote, one of them a lawyer upvote, one a student upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems -- you rewrite your @lawyervotes array during the next iteration. One of the ways out would be to append it instead (using something like:

```
@lawyervotes = []
@answers.each do |a|
  @lawyervotes <<= AnswerVote.where({:answer_id => a.id, :lawyervote => true}).reload
  ...
end
```

But it is super-terrible, non-Rails style. As I mentioned above, you *do* not need this iteration through @answers, you simply write:

*UPDATED*

```
@lawyervotes = @question.answers.map {|a| a.answer_votes.lawyers}.reject!(&:empty?).flatten
@studentvotes = @question.answers.map {|a| a.answer_votes.students}.reject!(&:empty?).flatten
```

And in you AnswerVotes model:

```
scope :lawyers, where(lawyervote: true)
scope :students, where(studentvote: true)
```

Comment: oops, sorry. How do I get the local variable 'a' (in a.answer_votes.lawyers) without looping through? This code is in the Questions show controller. In order to get a local variable 'a', I need to loop through `@answers = @questions.answers` as shown in the op

Comment: Thanks. When there's no lawyervotes, your code returns an array inside an array, like this `[[]]`. Therefore, when my view logic checks to see if there's lawyer votes like this `<% if  @lawyervotes.size === 1 %>`, it shows there's 1 lawyer vote even though there's none. This is due to the arrray inside the array. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Doesn't work. Empty not a method for AR Relation: undefined method `empty' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: Also added `flatten`, it converts resulting array of arrays to single-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `lawyervotes` array as empty for second answer as the second answer has only one `AnswerVote` with `laywervote = nil` and `studentvote = true` :) So the vote is present in the `@studentvotes` variable.

If you inspect your `@studentvotes` as well, you will see your second vote printed in the second iteration of the loop.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Each answer has only one vote on it. The vote on one of the answers should be by a lawyer, and the vote on the other answer should be by a student.  That's what the console shows. Anyways, I've moved past that problem with Dmitry's answer, but still have one small issue, as explained in my comment to his answer with the empty array inside the array being considered as 1 result by my view logic.